# GDB can't see global variable when inside another function of Golang program

Tags: go, gdb

I have simple code in Go language:

```
package main
import "fmt"

var a int = 0

func printit () {
    var b int = 1
    fmt.Printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b) // here is breakpoint

}

func main() {
    printit()
  }
```

I've set breakpoint at line 8. When breakpoint is hit I tried to print variable 'a' inside gdb console using command:

```
print a
```

But GDB said:

```
 No symbol "a" in current context.
```

This problem is only on variable 'a', printing value of 'b' is ok.

This problem occurs only inside function printit(), when I tried print variable 'a' from function main() it was ok.
Why is this happening?

PS: program compiled with  `go build -gcflags=all="-N -l" source.go`

PPS: This happens only in Go programming language, I tried similar  code in C++ and no problem.

Comment: Looks like a gdb bug, which you might want to [report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

Comment: Maybe GDB doesn't understand Go code. 


As is described on this page: https://golang.org/doc/gdb


__GDB does not understand Go programs well. The stack management, threading, and runtime contain aspects that differ enough from the execution model GDB expects that they can confuse the debugger and cause incorrect results__

Comment: After reading through your [link](https://golang.org/doc/gdb), I'm not really surprised that gdb doesn't handle go correctly, since these are basically known problems, and they chose not to fix them. Have you tried debugging with [Delve](https://github.com/go-delve/delve), like stated there?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `print main.a` in gdb.

Comment: ```print main.a``` works in gdb.